# Примеры использования и рабочие решения при разработке приложения

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Перебрал кучу сайтов, пробовал все примеры, просто копировал код из примеров, дабы увидеть это в действии - но, все что я пробывал, было с ошибками, по крайней мере у меня ругался Eclipse . Библиотеки в проект я добавил.
С последнего приложения я получил вылет с логом:

```
09-16 18:02:00.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(387): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

09-16 18:02:00.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(387): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ru.mystory.text-1.apk]
```

Прошу примера использования RecyclerView, я уже почти отчаялся в поисках.
Буду очень благодарен вам за это!

Comment: Вот полностью законченный рабочий сэмпл - разбирайтесь:https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Довольно часто в примерах кода, особенно в статьях из интернета, приводится не полный завершенный рабочий код, а только какие-то основные моменты. Полную же реализацию предлагается додумывать самостоятельно, что часто ставит, особенно новичков, в тупик, так как пример не работает.
Что же делать?

Лучшим решением здесь может быть изучение оттестированного законченного примера - сэмпла, который оформлен в виде проекта. Его можно запустить у себя на устройстве и подробно разобрать, как все работает, испробовать какие то идеи и протестировать их, не засоряя основной проект и вообще набраться "хорошего тона" в программировании и стиле кода, так как сэмплы эти пишут, как правило люди опытные.

Для андроид гугл предлагает довольно внушительную подборку таких сэмплов, которые являют собой законченные рабочие оттестированные проекты по всем основным паттернам и юзкейсам этой платформы.

Получить их можно не менее, чем четырьмя способами:

1. Самый простой. В *Android Studio* интегрирован инструмент, позволяющий с минимальным количеством усилий выбрать сэмпл и тут же перенести в свою IDE и начать тестировать. Идем по пути: *File -> New -> Import Sample* и видим такой мастер:

[image: screen]

Здесь есть удобная навигация,поиск и краткое описание и даже превьюшка. Щелкая по кнопке *Next* и выполняя несложные действия вы можете очень легко заполучить желаемое.

2. То же самое можно [получить и с *GitHub*](https://github.com/googlesamples) (даже ссылки на него указаны в мастере) - иногда это удобнее, когда нужно только подглядеть немного позабытое, а не весь проект тащить или поделится с кем то решением.
3. Следующий способ - скачать сэмплы через SDK Manager. В пакетах, предложенных к скачиванию, в каждом API есть пункт *Samples for SDK* установив этот пакет вы получите сборник исходников по пути (с разделением по версиям SDK):

   > C: .. \Android\Sdk\samples\

Нет никакой надобности скачивать сэмплы для всех SDK, с каждой новой версией они как правило просто дополняются. потому достаточно установить сэмплы только самого "свежего"  SDK - они будут наиболее полные.
Такой вариант подойдет для выборочного копипаста в свой проект.

4. Копия этих сэмплов хранится так же и на всеми нами любимом ресурсе `developer.android.com` - [Сэмплы](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/samples/index.html). Это, пожалуй, самый неудобный способ проникнуться сокральным знанием великих, но он есть и поэтому указан.

Кроме того никто пока не заблокировал (хотя и пытались) такой бесценный ресурс, как [*GitHub*](https://github.com/).

Если необходимого сэмпла нет в коллекции гугл - не стоит отчаиваться, есть множество увлеченных людей, которые, по доброте душевной, пишут прекрасные примеры и целые приложения и абсолютно безвозмездно дарят их всем. Ваша задача - только найти их поиском на гитхабе по каким то ключевым словам и не дасть этому благодарному труду остаться не востребованным.

PS: Изучение исходников - лучшая школа программиста. От примеров в статьях их выгодно отличает то, что они, как правило,точно рабочие, но не всегда достаточно откомментированы, чтобы понять, что происходит. Впрочем, чаще комментариев вполне хватает.

Comment: Я так в 1998м изучал Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что у вас кроме **RecyclerView** либы подключены также последние версии `supportLib` **v4** и **v7**